# Google places API automatically get place from a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-places-api, angular-controller

In my Page I'm querying my backend to get an address and placing that address in my input. 
Now using Jquery I get that input value and want to get the place from google places api.

```
//placing value from parameter my input 
 var pickup = $state.params.bookingInfo.address;
 $("#address").val(pickup);

//Calling for places
autocomplete = new.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("address"));
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
});
```

Here I'm getting places as undefined as there is no event in the map.

All I need is how do I get the place with the address i get from my query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the official Google dev docs and source sample found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

In your case, you can embed this code in as is; tweak the CSS in the head (for example hide the map if it isn't needed); copy the sample code and plugin your key and do some live editing until you figure out how to make it work best with your existing page; first try it as-is just to ensure it's working properly; after you can begin modding it to fit your needs. I was in your situation before actually, I found the source above to be the most helpful in getting the place details callback. Hope it helps you as well.

Comment: awesome! I'm glad you resolved it :) if my answered helped please don't forget to accept it :)